# Scrollbar height changes on click

Tags: html, scrollbar

Am using 'perfect-scrollbar' to have some scrollbars in my html and strangely the height of the scrollbar changes on hovering on the element from the mouse-pad. This is just driving me crazy as am unable to figure out or resolve this odd behaviour. Please help.

[Edit]: After some more analysis it seems the scroll-bar height doesn't automatically adjust because the data over which am using the scroll-bar is dynamically loaded. After some surfing, i found that calling .perfectScrollbar('update') should resolve the issue. But it is not really working. Would anyone have any idea on this please?

My HTML on initial page load:

[image: page as it appears on initial upload]

Page on mouse hovering/clicking:

[image: after click/hovering on the element]

html corresponding to initial page load:

[image: The html wrt the initial upload]

html change in 'height' upon mouse hovering:

[image: See, the height value just changes to 22 from 177!]

Comment: Your style is getting changed in case when hovered.

Comment: Try to find from where this style gets applied. You can see that in developer console.

Comment: Am going dizzy now :( . The console doesn't really tell me where is this height attribute getting read from! Checked the whole of css file, nothing has a height of 177px or 20px actually!